# Automatically number sections in RMarkdown up to certain level

Tags: r-markdown

With option `number_sections: true`, all sections are numbered. Adding `{-}` to the title will suppress the numbering of one specific title. However is it possible to automatically number up to a certain level? Maybe an additional option `number_sections_up_to_level`

```
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections_up_to_level: 2
---

# First Level

## Second Level

### Third Level
```

which would produce the output below

## 1. First Level

### 1.1 Second Level

#### Third Level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the release of [Quarto](https://quarto.org/), this is now easily possible for all kind of document formats:

```
---
title: "Test"
number-sections: true
number-depth: 2
---
  
  
# Hallo World

This is the first Chapter

## Sub Chapter

Still numbered

### Sub-sub Chapter

No longer numbered
```

See for example in the [documentation about books](https://quarto.org/docs/books/book-structure.html#section-numbers).